# What is the term for data which do not include multiple variables needed for controlling confounding in analyses?

Tags: dataset, terminology, confounding

I have a terminology question that I couldn't answer by googling.

What is the term for data which do not include multiple analytically relevant variables needed for controlling confounding in analyses? Or how you would describe such "limited" data with few words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Residual confounding.You could also call it biased, misleading, and unsuitable for answering the question.